# How can I set auto increment of a primary key in the table in SQL DEVELOPER?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have been trying to set a "w_no" to auto_increment like we do in MySQL but its been giving error.

How do we set auto increment in sql developer? Can we do by code or have to do something else?

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38PPg.png)

```
CREATE TABLE ward (
      w_no      INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      wname     VARCHAR(30),
      w_loc     VARCHAR(30),
      phone_no  NUMERIC(10, 0),
      sno       INT
);

/*alter table ward ;*/  /*Can we do auto_increment using alter table here*/
```

Comment: Does Oracle have a `VARCHAR` data type?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yeah. I have been using it. Never gave me the error.

Comment: I would avoid using `VARCHAR`. Oracle recommends not to use it: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, Oracle has VARCHAR data type. It is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype, however, it is strongly recommended to use `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: For auto increment, varchar is not the best option.  Use an IDENTITY type or a sequence object.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you. I will stop using VARCHAR.

Comment: @alexherm No. I want auto increment with "w_no" which is INT.

Comment: @Serum - you have missed the point

Answer (score 6):

Don't use VARCHAR, use VARCHAR2

Also, if you want help, try the CREATE TABLE dialogs.

We'll create the table, PK, sequence, and trigger for you.

Or, if you're on 12c or higher version of database, you can use the IDENTITY clause.

[image]

Then click on the DDL page of the wizard, we'll show you the code, so you don't have to guess what the dialog is doing.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
(
  COLUMN1 INTEGER NOT NULL 
, COLUMN2 VARCHAR2(20) 
, COLUMN3 VARCHAR2(20) 
, CONSTRAINT TABLE1_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    COLUMN1 
  )
  ENABLE 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE TABLE1_SEQ;

CREATE TRIGGER TABLE1_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN
      SELECT TABLE1_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.COLUMN1 FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
```

Comment: What are the odds that in the next 30 years `VARCHAR` will be changed and `VARCHAR2` remains stable?

Comment: I would be $1,000 that varchar2 remains stable and that if you find any bugs with varchar they won't be addressed or fixed.

Comment: Yeap.  ```varchar2``` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think Oracle introduced IDENTITY data types until 12c.  In which case you should use a SEQUENCE object in place of the lack of IDENTITY type.

Comment: Can you please give me instructions on how can I do it? @alexherm

Comment: IDENTITY data types are really the best for what you want to achieve, but I dont think they are available in 11i.  Here is a decent link on how to work with SEQUENCES - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Answer (score 2):

Since your Oracle database version in `11g`,you need to use **SEQUENCE** object to increment the primary key. See documentation for [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314).

You could refer the sequence number while inserting the data. Or else, you could create a **TRIGGER** to increment the value in the table using `sequence.NEXTVAL`.

From version `12c` onward, Oracle introduced **IDENTITY** columns which could be used as:

```
NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

On a separate note, please avoid using `VARCHAR` as [Oracle strongly recommends to use VARCHAR2 instead](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822) to store variable-length character strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this topic, I would like to make some additions to previous replies.

You do not have to create an additional `trigger` to be associated with your primary key. First, you should create your sequence nevertheless.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE some_schema_name.your_sequence_name
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

After that, all you have to do is to assign this sequence to your PK field while creating your table. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE some_schema_name.my_table (
ID NUMBER(8) default "some_schema_name"."your_sequence_name".nextval NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
NAME NVARCHAR2(200)
);
```